# micronaut how to add initialization code such as BootStrap.groovy in Grails

Tags: micronaut

I use Micronaut to develop my micro service.
When the service start, it needs to initialize some variables and query data from database.

I know in Grails, I can write my code in BootStrap.groovy. I wonder if there is similar place when developing an application with Micronaut ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a singleton that's annotated as an event listener, listening for `StartupEvent`:

```
import io.micronaut.context.annotation.Requires;
import io.micronaut.context.event.StartupEvent;
import io.micronaut.runtime.event.annotation.EventListener;
import jakarta.inject.Singleton;

import javax.transaction.Transactional;
import java.util.Arrays;

@Singleton
@Requires(notEnv = "test")
class Bootstrap {

    @EventListener
    @Transactional
    void init(StartupEvent event) {
        // do startup initialization here
    }
}
```

The class name and method name aren't important - Micronaut finds the method annotated with `@EventListener` and calls it when that event is fired.

You can remove the `@Transactional` annotation - that's only needed if you're doing database inserts/updates/etc. that should run in a single transaction.

You can also remove `@Requires(notEnv = "test")` which disables the bean when running tests, unless you want to run the initialization logic for tests.